# Item name as field instead of Property?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there a way to get at an Item's Name property as if it were a field?  I've got a bunch of code that attempts to generalize Item behavior in UserControls... and takes properties that are used as field names.  For instance, I have a generic DropDownList control that takes two strings, one for the DataTextField and another for DataValueField.  But this breaks down when I want to just use the item NAME as a value:

```
string DataValueField = "SomeField";
string DataTextField = "Name";

ListItem x = new ListItem(myItem[DataTextField], myItem[DataValueField]);  //OOOPS!
```

Suggestions?  Other than writing really hacky code that checks specifically for "Name"?  Cuz I already got that covered.

Comment: Can't you use myItem.Name instead of myItem[DataTextField]?

Comment: No... that's the whole point of this question. :)  I want consistent access to the information.  I want to pass a string as a parameter to indicate which field to access.  I cannot use DataTextField as a property without jumping through a bunch of Reflection hoops.

Comment: @Bryan Don't you want to use the display name for this? The display name has a fallback to the item name, if no display name is filled in. But the display name can be translated if needed for an item. You can get the id of the display name with the constant `Sitecore.FieldIDs.DisplayName`.

Comment: Great suggestion, Kevin.  Forgot about the fallback value here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access this easily without reflection as you have stated, even then it may not be that clean.

I would be tempted to write a simple extension method to handle the Sitecore properties not available in the Fields collection:

```csharp
public static string GetField(this Item item, string fieldName)
{
    switch (fieldName)
    {
        case "Name":
            return item.Name;
        case "DisplayName":
            return item.DisplayName;
        default:
            return item[fieldName];
    }
}
```

And then it's a simple case of:

```csharp
string DataValueField = "SomeField";
string DataTextField = "Name";

ListItem x = new ListItem(myItem.GetField(DataTextField), myItem.GetField(DataValueField));
```

Comment: Thanks jammykam.  I think this is probably the cleanest solution, although remembering to use GetField() in these situations will be a chore.

Answer (score 2):

You actually can (or could with earlier version of Sitecore)!

I wrote a [blog post](http://seankearney.com/post/Getting-a-special-field-value-in-Sitecore) on how to get 'special field' values a couple years ago.

TL;DR

Supported 'special fields' are:

```
@id = Item.ID.ToString()
@key = Item.Key
@lang = Item.Language.ToString()
@mid = Item.BranchID.ToString()
@name = Item.Name
@tid = Item.TemplateID.ToString()
@ver = Item.Version.ToString()
```

Example:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content");

string id = item["@id"];
string key = item["@key"];
string lang = item["@lang"];
string mid = item["@mid"];
string name = item["@name"];
string tid = item["@tid"];
string ver = item["@ver"];

Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(id == item.ID.ToString(), "No match");
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(key == item.Key.ToString(), "No match");
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(lang == item.Language.ToString(), "No match");
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(mid == item.BranchId.ToString(), "No match");
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(name == item.Name.ToString(), "No match");
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(tid == item.TemplateID.ToString(), "No match");
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(ver == item.Version.ToString(), "No match");
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can not. You will have to write a code like jammykam suggested.
Take a look at the database you will see that Name is a column in the Items table and there is no entry for it in the Fields table.

[image]

You see in this example that 'Display Name' is a field.

cheers